# Cannot install nativescript

Tags: node.js, nativescript, npm-install

I'm trying to install NativeScript and I am getting this error when I do

npm i -g nativescript

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "i" "-g" "nativescript" npm ERR! node v8.9.1 npm ERR! npm  v4.0.3
>
> npm ERR! Cannot read property 'assert-plus' of undefined
>
> . . .
>
> npm ERR! Cannot read property 'minimist' of undefined

when I run this command on a Mac, I get:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: abbrev@1.1.0
>   (node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev):
>   npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, rename
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev'
>   -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.abbrev.DELETE'
>
> npm ERR! path
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! syscall rename npm
>   ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex'
>   -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ansi-regex.DELETE'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent

Does anyone know how to work around this? I have the latest version of Node and npm. Maybe that is my problem? Does anyone know what version would work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was interesting to me. I had had npm 4.01 on the Windows machine and getting the lastest (npm i -g npm@latest), 5.5.1, made it work. On the Mac machine I already had 5.5.1 but rolling that back to 4.1.1 allowed the install to work. So on Windows, 5.5.1 was good but not on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using windows you need to run this for installation

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"
```

See https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup section **Windows**

Comment: Yes, that is step 3, but step 2 is installing the CLI which is failing. I did try this and it installs the Android requirements, but not the CLI itself.